# QSqlQueryModel TableView custom delegate

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qsqlquerymodel

I have a QSqlQueryModel and a TableView to display the data from the model. The code and output data results are fine. But, I just **want to display an image in front of each row** in the TableView. However, with my current QML code, the image is repeated along with the elements in my table columns. I have added example screenshots for reference

***Current Output (Screenshot)***

[image]

***What I want***

[image]

My Code is as below

**Test.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Page {

    id : somepageid

    TableView{
        id: testTable
        model: QueryModel
        height: 500
        width: 400
        delegate:
            Row{

            Image {
                id: statusImg
                height: 18
                width: 18
                source: "../../../Images/icons/tick.png"
            }

            Text {
                text: display
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**QueryModel.cpp**

```
#include "querymodel.h"


QueryModel::QueryModel(QObject *parent): QSqlQueryModel(parent)
{

}

void QueryModel::setQuery(const QString &query, const QSqlDatabase &db)
{
    QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(query, db);
    generateRoleNames();
}

void QueryModel::setQuery(const QSqlQuery &query)
{
    QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(query);
    generateRoleNames();
}

QVariant QueryModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value;

    if(role < Qt::UserRole) {
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    }
    else {
        int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
        QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }
    return value;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> QueryModel::roleNames() const
{
    return {{Qt::DisplayRole, "display"}};
}

void QueryModel::callSql()
{
    QSqlDatabase dbMysql = QSqlDatabase::database();
    this->setQuery(this->tmpSql(), dbMysql);
}

QString QueryModel::tmpSql() const
{
    return m_tmpSql;
}

void QueryModel::setTmpSql(QString tmpSql)
{
    if (m_tmpSql == tmpSql)
        return;

    m_tmpSql = tmpSql;
    emit tmpSqlChanged(m_tmpSql);
}

void QueryModel::generateRoleNames()
{
    m_roleNames.clear();
    for( int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
        m_roleNames.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, record().fieldName(i).toUtf8());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a [`Loader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html):

```
// ...
delegate: Row{
    Loader{
        active: model.column === 0
        sourceComponent: Image {
            id: statusImg
            height: 18
            width: 18
            source: "../../../Images/icons/tick.png"
        }
    }
    Text {
        text: model.display
    }
}
// ...
```